# Azure Function Timer Trigger & API management - Manual execution returns 404

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have a function app with:

- a few functions triggered by a **Timer Trigger**
- and some triggered by the **HTTP Trigger**.

I have **also an Azure API Management** service set up for the function app, where the **HTTP Triggered** functions have their endpoints defined.

I am trying to trigger one of my timer triggered functions manually as per the guide here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http

I am however getting a 404 result in Postman, despite the seemingly correct URL and `x-functions-key`.

The function:
[image]

The key:

[image]

The request:

[image]

I also noticed that:

- if I don't include the `x-functions-key` header, then I get `401 Unauthorized` result
- and if I include an **incorrect** key, then I get `403 Forbidden`.

**Could it be related to the API management service being set up for the function app?**

**How can I troubleshoot this further?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have managed to solve it.

It turns out that Azure Functions timer trigger requires **six parts cron expression** (I was only aware of [the five part style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview))

Without that, it does not work - **sadly this is not easily noticeable in the UI**.
I have realized that by investigating **Application Insights** logs:

[image]

The function page shows that **everything is fine**:

[image]

**Changing the CRON format has fixed the 404 issue and I started getting 202 Accepted response.**

### As a bonus note, I have to add:

Even though the response was 202 Accepted, the triggering didn't work correctly, because **my function return type was `Task<IActionResult>` which is not accepted for timer triggered functions.**

Again, only ApplicationInsights showed that anything is wrong:

> The 'MonkeyUserRandom' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MonkeyUserRandom'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter '$return' to type IActionResult&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

That's a bonus tip for a 'manual triggering of non-http function does not work'.

Comment: Ran into the same problem - I was also using the five-part CRON syntax. Changing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I test it in my side, it works fine. Please refer to the below screenshot:

[image]

Please check if you request `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/TimerTrigger1` but not `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/TimerTrigger`. Note it's "**TimerTrigger1**".

I requst with `..../TimerTrigger` at first test because the document shows us `QueueTrigger`, and it response 404.

Comment: Have you got the API Management as well?

Comment: @Bartosz I haven't test it in APIM. I will test it.

Comment: Thanks - I have updated the question with details of how I send the requests etc. It's for an open source project (https://dailycomic.github.io/)

Comment: @Bartosz It also works fine in my apim and the difference between your function and mine is your function was deployed from local and I created it on portal directly. But I also test with create a timer trigger function in visual studio and then deploy it to portal, it also can be triggered manually. So it's strange.

Comment: @Bartosz It seems the path of your function on portal is strange. My path looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub7pi.png), but yours is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDfND.png). It seems your function has one more level than mine.

Comment: Nah, that's because I accessed it through resource group first - the breadcrumbs show like a 'history' of pages that I went through.
Thanks for your investigation though!

Comment: @Bartosz And I also find your function has one more level than mine in local. The `entryPoint` of my function looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezyda.png) and your function `entryPoint` is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMVYp.png). I'm not sure if it will lead to 404 not found. Could you please have a try with create another timer trigger function app in visual stuido with all of configuration as default and then deploy it to portal. Then test if it can be triggered manually.